# Custom iterator implementation returning OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, iterator, opencv

I have written an adapter class that allows iteration over the rows of a `Mat` object from OpenCV. For those interested, here is the [Mat documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat), but the salient points are as follows:

- `Mat` is a reference-counted header to a shared data buffer.
- `Mat::row()` returns another `Mat`, which provides a view of a single row of the larger `Mat`.
- `Mat_<T>` is a templated version of `Mat` offering the same interface but better type safety. `Mat_<T>` and `Mat` can be converted to one another.

This is my first attempt at writing custom iterators, so I am interested in feedback on correctness and general points to improve. It seems like my use of `mutable` is suspect, but I don't know if I can avoid it.

Here are the class definitions:

**RowRange.hpp**

```
#ifndef CV_ADAPTERS_ROWRANGE_HPP
#define CV_ADAPTERS_ROWRANGE_HPP

#include <iterator>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

namespace cv
{

template <typename T>
class RowRangeConstIterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
    {
    public:
        RowRangeConstIterator()
        : data()
        , row()
        , position()
        {}

        RowRangeConstIterator(const cv::Mat_<T>& m, int index)
        : data(m)
        , row()
        , position(index)
        {
            CV_DbgAssert(position >= 0 && position <= data.rows);
        }

        // Dereference
        const cv::Mat_<T>& operator*() const
        {
            setRow();
            return row;
        }

        const cv::Mat_<T>* operator->() const
        {
            setRow();
            return &row;
        }

        // Logical comparison
        bool operator==(const RowRangeConstIterator& that) const
        {
            return this->position == that.position;
        }

        bool operator!=(const RowRangeConstIterator& that) const
        {
            return !(*this == that);
        }

        bool operator<(const RowRangeConstIterator& that) const
        {
            return this->position < that.position;
        }

        bool operator>(const RowRangeConstIterator& that) const
        {
            return this->position > that.position;
        }

        bool operator<=(const RowRangeConstIterator& that) const
        {
            return !(*this > that);
        }

        bool operator>=(const RowRangeConstIterator& that) const
        {
            return !(*this < that);
        }

        // Increment
        RowRangeConstIterator& operator++()
        {
            ++position;
            return *this;
        }

        RowRangeConstIterator operator++(int) const
        {
            RowRangeConstIterator tmp(*this);
            ++(*this);
            return tmp;
        }

    protected:
        void setRow() const
        {
            row = data.row(position);
        }

        cv::Mat_<T> data;
        mutable cv::Mat_<T> row;
        int position;
    };

template <typename T>
class RowRangeIterator : public RowRangeConstIterator<T>
{
public:
    RowRangeIterator()
    : RowRangeConstIterator<T>()
    {}

    RowRangeIterator(const cv::Mat_<T>& m, int index)
    : RowRangeConstIterator<T>(m, index)
    {}

    // Dereference
    cv::Mat_<T>& operator*() const
    {
        this->setRow();
        return this->row;
    }

    cv::Mat_<T>* operator->() const
    {
        this->setRow();
        return &this->row;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class RowRange
{
public:
    typedef RowRangeConstIterator<T> const_iterator;
    typedef RowRangeIterator<T> iterator;

    RowRange(cv::Mat m)
    : data(m)
    {
        CV_Assert(m.type() == cv::DataType<T>::type);
    }

    RowRange(cv::Mat_<T> m)
    : data(m) {}

    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return const_iterator(data, 0);
    }

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(data, 0);
    }

    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return const_iterator(data, data.rows);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(data, data.rows);
    }

    const_iterator cbegin() const
    {
        return begin();
    }

    const_iterator cend() const
    {
        return end();
    }

private:
    cv::Mat_<T> data;
};

template <typename T>
RowRange<T> make_RowRange(cv::Mat_<T> m)
{
    return RowRange<T>(m);
}

} // namespace cv

#endif /* CV_ADAPTERS_ROWRANGE_HPP */
```

And an example usage (More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/mrollins/opencv-adapters)):

**main.cpp**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "RowRange.hpp"

int main()
{
    cv::Mat m2 = cv::Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
    for (auto row : cv::RowRange<uchar>(m2))
    {
        row(1) = 255;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not into C++, but I like how you've named the operator parameters `that` and go `this` vs `that`.

Comment: Looks handy. Minor thing: `data` is not the best name for a `cv::Mat_` member, since it is the same as the name of the data pointer within `cv::Mat`; I was confused first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a CV expert.

Overall, LGTM.

- Relational operators (`==, !=, <, >` etc) should not be members but friends. If such operators do not treat their operands symmetrically, expect problems with implicit conversion.
- It is recommended to define `operator>` in terms of `operator<`.
- I don't see why `row` should be a member.
- I understand that `position` is declared `int` just because `cv::Mat_::rows` is `int` (which is a shame). It'd be nice to have a type of `position` inferred.
- Last, but not least. This iterator can serve a much wider spectrum of classes than just `cv::Mat`. Its only dependency on the underlying class is in `rows` and `row` methods.

Comment: I made `row` a member because I'm worried about returning a pointer to a temporary in `operator->`. I'm pretty sure that returning `&data.row(position)` will invoke UB. That said, I'm not 100% sure, so I erred on the side of caution. Do you have further thoughts on this? It's the point that I'm most concerned about.

Comment: As I said, I am not a CV expert. It just looks strange that a member is set on demand. Much more naturally looking is `row(data.row(position))` in the constructor.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I can't set `row` in the constructor, because `position` can be mutated by the increment operators. Then dereferencing the iterator gives the wrong result.

Comment: @vnp: OpenCV won't copy the data if you do `row = data.row(position);` it will just return a submatrix of the original matrix, sharing the same piece of memory.